# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shapiro'

Tags: pandas, scipy

Why do I get this error when executing the following code?

```
import numpy as np

import scipy.stats as stats
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('DJ_splicing_data_plus_spliceAI.csv')

for column in df:
    print(column)
    data = df[column].values
    stats, p_value = stats.shapiro(data)
```

However,

```
stats, p_value = stats.shapiro(df["DG-L"])
```

doesn't give me any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first iteration, `stats` is the module `scipy.stats`.

At the second iteration, `stats` is the first value returned by `scipy.stats.shapiro` (i.e a `float`)

```
import numpy as np

import scipy.stats as stats
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('DJ_splicing_data_plus_spliceAI.csv')

for column in df:
    print(column)
    data = df[column].values
    statistic, p_value = stats.shapiro(data)
#      ^-- rename stats to statistic so as not to overwrite the stats module
```